# Inquiry about JDBC, not supported ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I have got two questions related to the same bit of code:

```
CachedRowSet cachedRow = new CachedRowSetImpl();
cachedRow.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test");
cachedRow.setUsername("root");
cachedRow.setPassword("StackOverKindOfThing");
cachedRow.setCommand("SELECT * FROM books");
cachedRow.execute();
int [] arrayKey = {1};

//cachedRow.setKeyColumns(arrayKey); // I can even omit this line and it works anyway;
cachedRow.next();
cachedRow.updateString(2, "ball");
cachedRow.updateRow();  
cachedRow.acceptChanges();//it works with cachedRow.acceptChanges(con) where con
                          //has been initialized and has been set on setAutoCommit(false);
```

That's the exception I am getting by using a CachedRowSet set with .setUrl("url");

```
at CachedThingSet.main(CachedThingSet.java:31)
javax.sql.rowset.spi.SyncProviderException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
```

1) I would like to know why I can insert data into the database even though the [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/cachedrowset.html#setting-key-columns) says it cannot be possible (the `setKeyColumn()` method is commented out):

> Setting Key Columns
>
> If you are going make any updates to the crs object and want those
>   updates saved in the database, you must set one more piece of
>   information: the key columns.

And why I have to set up a connection with `autocommit(false)` in order to use a `CachedRowSet` (updating a row) otherwise I get a `SyncProviderException: can't call commit when autocommit=true`
Is there anyway I can set the connection got from `setUrl("url");` without using `acceptChanges(con)` where con is another connection set with `autocommit(false)`

Comment: if you use preparedstatement then this type of error will not be shown

Comment: @javaBeginner Ok thanks however I would like to know why I get this error... in the tutorial is not specified that if applied an error should occur.

Comment: i am not familiar with CachedRowSet but i do have experience in JDBC.If you need help in how to connect with mysql and inserting,retireving or any other DB related activities then i can help.Sorry not having ideas in CachedRowSet

Comment: You need to set `autoCommit` to false via the appropriate argument in the database URL. Bizarre that `CachedRowSet` doesn't do this internally.